# How to dynamically proxy_pass URLs in NGINX

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

For security reasons i'm trying to reverse proxy the access to some HPE servers' iLO (out of band management card).

I would need one single reverse proxy server to allo access to many iLOs in backend, depending on the URL used by the client when requesting NGINX.

Using proxy_pass, regex and variables it works just fine for the first request, as i have the ability to add in the first URL the IP of the backend iLO to be passing through to.

Problems begin when the said iLO then asks the client to contact some other URLs for the js, css, and other files and pages. I can't add anything to those URLs obviously.

Is there a way to "attach" a client to a specific backend iLO depending on the first URL that was used to go through NGINX?

Thanks a lot

I tried adding http headers but i dont seem to be able to understand them

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.